# protobuf-net transcoder for EnyimMemcached problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc, protobuf-net, enyim.caching

Is the transcoder from protobuf-net to enyim cache deprecated? [distributed caching with protobuff-net](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com.br/2010/01/distributed-caching-with-protobuf-net.html)

Setting my Enyim config just like this [app.config](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/Examples/app.config) causes an error when I try to start the MemcachedClient()
The same for using

> transcoder type="ProtoBuf.Caching.Enyim.NetTranscoder"/

```
System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2146233036
Message=The type initializer for 'Enyim.Caching.MemcachedClient' threw an exception.
Source=Enyim.Caching
TypeName=Enyim.Caching.MemcachedClient
StackTrace:
   at Enyim.Caching.MemcachedClient..ctor()
   at Global.asax.cs:line 31
InnerException: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
   HResult=-2146232062
   Message=The value of the property 'transcoder' cannot be parsed. The error is: Object reference   not set to an instance of an object. (\web.config line 207)
   Source=System.Configuration
   BareMessage=The value of the property 'transcoder' cannot be parsed. The error is: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   StackTrace:
        at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(String[] keys, SectionInput input, Boolean isTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult)
        at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult, Boolean getLkg, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
        at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
        at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
        at System.Web.HttpContext.GetSection(String sectionName)
        at System.Web.Configuration.HttpConfigurationSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
        at System.Web.Configuration.HttpConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String configKey)
        at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
        at Enyim.Caching.MemcachedClient..cctor() in MemcachedClient.cs:line 25
   InnerException:
```

Both installed via nuget and using the latest version available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes (cough), of course that's there! Just see "protobuf-net.Enyim", i.e.

> PM> Install-Package protobuf-net.Enyim

(or use the GUI client)

To initialize, you need to configure the transcoder to be an instance of `ProtoBuf.Caching.Enyim.NetTranscoder` (as per the original instructions). If you are doing this via configuration, note that the assembly for this type is now `protobuf-net.Enyim`. If I assume the configuration file uses standard notation, then that means you would need to specify (in the config):

```
<transcoder type="ProtoBuf.Caching.Enyim.NetTranscoder,protobuf-net.Enyim" />
```

---

Original answer:

The enyim transcoder is not currently in nuget; however - I will *right now* take it upon myself to resurrect that, by adding a separate NuGet package (reference EnyimMemcached and protobuf-net) that adds this back in.

Random question... any chance you can point me at a binary memcached download for testing?

One reason this has lagged is that when I *first* wrote the enyim transcoder, memcached was a simple "run this" - but last time I looked it had gone all "enterprisey", and I couldn't track down a simple package that just had the memcached server. If you can show me where *that* is now, I'll get it working this weekend.

Comment: Will this work? the lastest version I found working 1.4.5. [x86](http://downloads.northscale.com/memcached-1.4.5-x86.zip)
[amd64](http://downloads.northscale.com/memcached-1.4.5-amd64.zip) I would gladly help if needed.

Comment: @TadeuMaia will look later - ta

Comment: @marc I used the link in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896/memcached-on-windows-x64#comment5692831_2356710) to get memcached 1.4.14 x64 [here](http://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.northscale.com/memcached-win64-1.4.4-14.zip)

Comment: For those who followed the original blog post and are having trouble, the correct config setting is `<transcoder type="ProtoBuf.Caching.Enyim.NetTranscoder,protobuf-net.Enyim" />`